# Enable form validation/required if fieldset is not disabled

Tags: javascript, html

I have a booking form, which requires validation. Some of the fields are enabled/disabled depending on previous options chosen. My problem is that I am restricted from submitting the form with the fields disabled as it waits for "valid" input data from the empty fields.

Is there a way which I can enable/disable required and data validation for these fields only if the fieldset is enabled?

**EDIT**
Here is the code I'm currently working with. The fieldset is enabled/disabled according to the selected radio button. I want the fields within the fieldset to be validated if the radio button is selected and the fields are enabled. Right now, if I try to submit the form with the fieldset disabled and validation/required existing on the fields, I am not able to submit the form due to required fields not filled/fields validation fails due to fields being empty.

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <div class="form-check">
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="oneRetOpt" id="returntrf" onclick="enableReturn()">
            Return
        </label>
    </div>
</div>


<fieldset id="returnfields" disabled>
    <div class="row" style="padding-bottom: 5px">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="transferTypeRet">Transfer Type:</label>
                <select class="form-control" placeholder="Transfer Type" id="transferTypeRet">
                    <option> </option>
                    <option>Direct Tranfser</option>
                    <option>Split Transfer</option>
                </select>
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="numadultsRet">Adults:</label>
                <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control" placeholder="Number of Adults" id="numadultsRet" >
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="numchildRet">Children:</label>
                <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control" placeholder="Number of Children (under 12 years old)" id="numchildRet" >
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" style="padding-bottom: 5px">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="datetimeret">Date and Time:
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="timeTooltip"
                       title="Provide flight landing or departure time for airport transfers">
                        <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></a>
                </label>
                <div class='input-group date form_datetime' data-date-format="dd MM yyyy - HH:ii" id='datetimeret'>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" style="padding-bottom: 5px">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="pickupret">Pick-up Location: </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Pick-up location" id="pickupret">
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="dropoffret">Drop-off Location: </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Drop-off location" id="dropoffret">
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function enableReturn() {
            document.getElementById("returnfields").disabled = false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This question needs work to be answerable. [Please follow this guide to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: can you add a code snippet with what you have so far?

Comment: Any Code examples? You could just not make the form field required and validate the input in javascript and give a respond according to the input. But this is just an idea, and not fitting to anything if there is no code attached to your question. 
In general, if a form field is required the form should not be submitted :)

Comment: @Mario updated.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider handling it in the submit logic of the form.  See sample below. You an even bypass certain inputs from validation if you can conditionally evaluate them.

```js
$("#myform").submit( function(event){
event.preventDefault();
var form = $("#myform");
console.log(form)
form.validate()
alert(form.valid()) 

form.children("#input1").remove()

form.validate()
alert(form.valid())


})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>

<form id = "myform" novalidate>
  <input id= "input1"  required>
  <input id= "input2"  required>
  <input type = "submit"> 
</form>
```

Comment: thank you for this, I have updated the question with code because as much as I get the logic behind your answer, I'm not sure if it applies for my scenario.